# PYQT: Use a string list as a parameter for an MS SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, pyqt4

I want a to write an SQL query in Microsoft SQL Server in PyQt of the type:

```
list=['Engineer', 'Doctor', 'Lawyer']

select * from Occupations where OccupationName in (list)
```

I have read various posts online but they seem to be for SQL Lite or MySQL databases. How would I do this for Microsoft SQL?

Also, in MS SQL the string values need to be enclosed in double quotes instead of single quotes used in the list items. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

this topic should help you! [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

btw:
You can write your params in CTE:

```
;with list as (
  select 'Engineer' as [occupation] union
  select 'Doctor' union
  select 'Lawyer'
)
select * from Occupations where OccupationName in (select occupationfrom from list)
```

or very simple like this:

```
 select * from Occupations where OccupationName in ('Engineer', 'Doctor', 'Lawyer')
```

Comment: Hi @dmitrycat : That is just an example, my actual list is generated after the user chooses options from a check list. So, I need to run a query for whatever the user checks, so it has to be dynamic

Comment: i understood a few later, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string i guess it's what you need